# Can I upload a document to an Issue in github?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I have a document that I would like to reference from a github issue, but there is not a way to upload it. Any ideas?

Comment: As of 11/03/2015 you can now upload these types of files: PNG, GIF, JPG, DOCX, PPTX, XLSX, TXT, or PDF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't currently attach files to github issues.

**Update**:

As of 2012-12-07, [images can be attached to issues](https://github.com/blog/1347-issue-attachments) via drag-and-drop.

Just drag the image into the text field for the issue.

Answer (score 3):

[ZenHub.io](http://ZenHub.io) Chrome plug-in will enable you to add any type of file to a github issue. It's stored on their server instead of github.com.  From their website...

> GitHub only allows you to upload image files. ZenHub adds the ability
>   to upload any type of file into issues and comments, transferring
>   securely to Amazon S3. With this you can really take your workflow to
>   the next level; try using GitHub for everything! Centralized
>   collaboration and transparency are awesome.

Update:

As of 11/03/2015 you can now upload these types of files to github without any extension or plug-in: PNG, GIF, JPG, DOCX, PPTX, XLSX, TXT, or PDF

Answer (score 2):

If you have an account in github, then you can upload your document in Github's own Gist service: [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com)

After add the link in a comment of issue.

I think this will help you

For more details, see this bug : [How to attach file to a github issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963205/how-to-attach-file-to-a-github-issue)