# How to attach file to a GitHub issue?

Tags: github, attachment, github-issues

I migrated with a project from Bitbucket to GitHub and I cannot find a way to attach a file to an issue (ex: screenshot, specs, etc).

How to do it?

Comment: Ok, the solution I found to fit me is: Keep the main repo on Bitbucket and make a mirror on Github (sorry Github) and also point all (eventually) Github issues to the Bitbucket counterpart.

Comment: as of today gitHub allows image upload in the issues

Comment: A nice way to get screenshots attached to issues is [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com/connect/github) - you can send screenshots with annotations directly from within your web app to GitHub Issues!

Comment: As of 11/03/2015 you can now upload these types of files to github without any extension or plug-in: PNG, GIF, JPG, DOCX, PPTX, XLSX, TXT, or PDF

Comment: Also accepts ZIP and GZ, which is handy for reproducers: https://help.github.com/articles/file-attachments-on-issues-and-pull-requests/

Comment: It's kind of shameful that we cannot add movies describing bugs to our issues on Github. 

Comment: @Jonny movies can be attached now see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65331650/2932052)

Answer (score 258, accepted):

<s>You upload it somewhere and add the link in a comment. GitHub's Issues is rather primitive and doesn't allow attaching files.</s>

**Update:** You can post images to GitHub issues now.  The easiest way is to copy the image (right click, Copy image) and then paste it into the text box where you describe the issue.

*OR*

Just drag and drop

Comment: Oh God, I was afraid of this answer :)

Comment: One easy place to do the upload is Github's own Gist service: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: This answer should probably be updated as Github now allows you to upload images for commets.

Comment: Unfortunately, Github doesn't allow upload of PDFs :(

Comment: Got so excited about copy paste but it didn't work for images (got [this](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1148376/4613386/2642505c-52d5-11e4-85e1-9691981b160d.png)) when copying from mac

Comment: i can prove that uploading with drad&drop works for me. Using OS X.

Comment: @Alex Why did you afraid?! The number of votes on your comment make me curious to know! :)

Comment: @Abraham My "afraid" comment was posted before Dominik updated his answer. I hope now makes sense.

Comment: @bjnord can you actually attach an image to a Gist? how u do that?

Comment: It would be great to add source code but I suppose you can use a gist for that.

Comment: @sampablokuper Github has added support for PDFs: https://imgur.com/UNogHDz (https://help.github.com/articles/file-attachments-on-issues-and-pull-requests/). Currently non-image attachments require write-access to the repository, "but there's also some discussion about lifting the permission restriction for non-image attachments" (according to Robert from Github support).

Comment: Attaching PDF files no longer requires write-access to a Github repo. So you can now freely attach PDF files to issues.

Comment: If the paste option does not occur, just drag and drop it.

Comment: How would this work for private repos? Would the image be private as well?

Comment: Is there a way to do it on the mobile website from a phone?

Comment: I have no way to copy the video, or drag & drop, is there a button for this?

Answer (score 45):

As of December 7, 2012, you can attach images by drag/drop or use a file chooser.  See https://github.com/blog/1347-issue-attachments for more details.

Answer (score 40):

To attach a file to an issue or pull request conversation, drag and drop it into the comment box.

The maximum size for files is 25MB and the maximum size for images is 10MB.

[image: Upload Image]

Comment: good answer. it's just markdown format. `![image](your_image_url)`

Comment: But it also auto-uploads the file to GitHub for you.

Answer (score 17):

[ZenHub.io](http://ZenHub.io) Chrome plug-in will enable you to add any type of file to a github issue. It's stored on ZenHub's AWS server instead of github.com.  From their website...

> GitHub only allows you to upload image files. ZenHub adds the ability
>   to upload any type of file into issues and comments, transferring
>   securely to Amazon S3. With this you can really take your workflow to
>   the next level; try using GitHub for everything! Centralized
>   collaboration and transparency are awesome.

Update:

As of 11/03/2015 you can now upload these types of files to github without any extension or plug-in: PNG, GIF, JPG, DOCX, PPTX, XLSX, TXT, or PDF

Comment: I just can't fine the feature in ZenHub.io. would you please show how it is done?

Comment: They may have removed it as it supported by github without plug-ins now.

Comment: so now we can attach any arbitrary files to a comment/issue? I just can't find it!

Answer (score 14):

As an illustration of the previous answers, see [this comment](https://github.com/jeremeamia/github-issues-toolbar/issues/17#issuecomment-2970427):

> I create a repository called `catfood` http://github.com/blueheadpublishing/catfood/ where I keep misc stuff (like screenshots and other attachments).
>   That way I can reference them in issues.

See [`https://github.com/blueheadpublishing/bookshop/issues/10`](https://github.com/blueheadpublishing/bookshop/issues/10#issuecomment-2966816)

> Some images showing the types of layout templates we want to have generated by templates:
>
> - [Example One - Three Percentage Columns](https://github.com/blueheadpublishing/catfood/blob/master/bookshop/three_perc_cols.png)
> - [Example Two - Two Percentage Columns Left](https://github.com/blueheadpublishing/catfood/blob/master/bookshop/two_perc_cols_lt.png)
> - [Example Three - Two Percentage Columns Right](https://github.com/blueheadpublishing/catfood/blob/master/bookshop/two_perc_cols_rt.png)

Back in 2009, GitHub expressed the intent to add [attachment to issues](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/github/xQlRASK5VuM/discussion).

> Attachments are something we'd like to add.

That topic [wasn't raised since in the GitHub group though](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/github/attachment)...

Answer (score 11):

The format for embedding images into a GitHub comment is:

```
Format:  ![Alt Text](url)
Example: ![GitHub Logo](/images/logo.png)
```

Comment: Thank you. An answer that doesn't require drag-and-drop. This is exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use  gist.github.com to upload any contents like code, log, html files etc. and share the link.

Comment: Its not clear how to use gist for that purpose. There is add file button, but it doesn't open attach window.

Answer (score 2):

8 years later (Dec. 2020), you can not only drag and drop images to PR/issues, but also... videos!
And in May 2021, this is [now generally available](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-05-13-video-uploads-now-generally-available/).

> ### [Video upload public beta](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-12-16-video-upload-public-beta/)
>
> You can now upload `.mp4` and `.mov` files to issue, pull request, and discussion comments to share reproduction steps, design ideas, and experience details with your team.
>
> [image]
>
> The public beta will gradually rollout to all GitHub accounts over the coming week.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a kludge but you could create a junk branch, then commit the file to that branch and purge it later.

EDIT: This script may be of use to you:

https://github.com/wereHamster/ghup

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way to embed images in issues using Skitch. Just set up Skitch sharing and auto-copy the URL to the clipboard. Then paste it in when writing up the issue. [I blogged about it here](http://www.g33klaw.com/2012/08/attaching-images-to-github-issues-with-skitch/).

Comment: I heard about this. The reviews in the Mac app store are pretty bad for the new version. And it sounds like they might have removed the functionality to do this image embedding.

Answer (score 1):

One quick/easy hack is to upload your attachment (say PDF or Office doc) to Dropbox, then include the Dropbox URL in the Github issue.

Mildly easier than using S3; many organizations are already using Dropbox; and Dropbox has good support for viewing many documents inline in the browser already.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I use for screenshots.

http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html

It's free, fast, automatically uploads the image and pastes a URL link to your clipboard which you can Ctrl-V into the GitHub issue instantly.

It was a big sigh of relief when I discovered this :)

Answer (score 0):

If your image is already uploaded to github, then you can attach raw link to issues. For example, if your image's location in github is:

`https://github.com/Qlio/someproj/blob/master/assets/image.png`

then you can can change `blob` to `raw` like this:

`https://github.com/Qlio/someproj/raw/master/assets/image.png`

and then you can use this link to show image:

```
![My cool Image](https://github.com/Qlio/someproj/raw/master/assets/image.png)
```

[image]