# How to attach images to github issues without dragndrop?

Tags: github

Is there a way to attach images to github issues without drag'n'drop, copy-pasting images or jumping through various hoops - just by using a file picker?

I find drag'n'drop very inconvenient, and copy-paste does not work in Firefox (on top of being rather inconvenient as well).

[Github help page](https://help.github.com/articles/file-attachments-on-issues-and-pull-requests/) only mentions drag'n'drop, or copy-paste for Chrome.

[The question here on adding images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963205/how-to-attach-file-to-a-github-issue) lists additional methods like creating a custom repository or wiki.

All of that is enough of a pain in the ass for me to ask a question here, hoping for a hidden way to use normal file picker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a file picker. Simply click on the *Attach files by dragging & dropping, selecting them, or pasting from the clipboard* field.
[image]

Comment: Oh dang, that's hidden. Somebody from Github should at least mention that in the help page, if not add a small button there.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is, its very simple, but not intuitive.

Consider this example where you want to comment:
[image]

Just click the highligted section with the text "Attach files by dragging and dropping, selecting them, ...".

Then a file dialog will open up:
[image]

Comment: Oh dang, that's hidden indeed. Somebody from Github should at least mention that in the help page, if not add a small button there. Accepting the other answer as it was a bit faster, but you get an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

setting firefox `about:config` `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` = `true` solves copy/paste for me.